# How to calculate a date column based on other 2 attributes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, sql-date-functions

I have to calculate a date field in run time based on 2 other fields.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Run Date   ||     Schedule       ||  Next Bill run date
-----------------------------[enter image description here][1]-----------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------
11/29/2018 ||     1st        ||  12/01/2018
----------------------------------------------------------
11/29/2018  ||     15th      ||   12/15/2018
----------------------------------------------------------
12/02/2018 ||   1st    ||   12/01/2019
----------------------------------------------------------
12/02/2018  ||  15th     ||      12/15/2018
----------------------------------------------------------
12/16/2018 ||   15th     ||     01/15/2019
----------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above scenario Next bill Run date should be populated based on the previous 2 column.
There are 4 conditions are there,

1. if the day(Run_date) between 2nd-15th of the same month and value of schedule is '15th' then "Next Bill Run" will be 15th of the same month.
2. if the day(Run_date) between 16th(same month) - 1st(next month) and value of schedule is '15th' then "Next Bill Run" will be 15th of the next month.
3. if the day(Run_date) between 2nd-15th of the same month and value of schedule is '1st' then "Next Bill Run" will be 1st of the next month.
4. if the day(Run_date) between 16th(same month) - 1st(next month) and value of schedule is '1st' then "Next Bill Run" will be 1st of the next month.

Please see the above table for better understanding. Please help me to find out a logic to implement "Next Bill Run". Appreciate your help.

I am thinking of using 'case' function to get the datepart() of the Run Date. But still confused with the implementation

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Can you post the code you wrote trying to implement this logic? Post what you've got and we'll help you troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this below query will help you.

```
set @lastDate := (SELECT LAST_DAY(now()) AS first_day);
set @firstDate := (SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(now()),INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) AS first_day);
select run_date,schedule,
case
when run_date between @firstDate and DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 14 DAY) and schedule ='15th' then DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
when run_date between DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY) and DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and schedule ='15th' then date_add(DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 14 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
when run_date between @firstDate and DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 14 DAY) and schedule ='1st' then DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
when run_date between DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY) and DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and schedule ='1st' then DATE_ADD(@firstDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
end
as next_bill_run_date 
from your_table
```

in SQL Server

```
declare @firstDate as date = '01-'+month(getdate())+'-'+year(getdate());
select run_date,schedule,
case
when run_date between @firstDate and DATEADD(DAY,14,@firstDate) and schedule ='15th' then DATEADD(DAY,14,@firstDate)
when run_date between DATEADD(DAY,15,@firstDate) and DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @firstDate) and schedule ='15th' then DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY,14,@firstDate))
when run_date between DATEADD(DAY,14,@firstDate) and schedule ='1st' then DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @firstDate)
when run_date between DATEADD(DAY,15,@firstDate) and DATEADD(MONTH, 1 @firstDate) and schedule ='1st' then DATEADD(MONTH, 1 @firstDate)
end
as next_bill_run_date 
from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, but I think these codes are for MySQL DB. I am currently using SQL Server. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I will give you the SQL server query. before that, is this the query you were looking for?

Comment: As per my initial understanding it looks fine. But I have to test it once before I am fully confident. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Thanks once again, Sandeep. I have hard coded the value of @firstDate as DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(getdate(),-1)) everywhere in the code. 
Still the result is coming as null.
Can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your logic is correct. Use the `case` statement along with some of the `DATE` functions in SQL SERVER. With my limited knowledge with SQL SERVER date functions i have framed the below query. You can still optimize this.

```
SELECT   
   RUN_DATE,SCHEDULE,
   case 
   when (DATEPART(month,run_date)=month(sysdatetime()) --checking same month
   and DATEPART(day, run_date) between 2 and 15 and Schedule='15th') --checking date between 2nd and 15th and schedule is 15th
   then DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date), 0)+14  --selecting 15th of same month

   when (DATEPART(month,run_date)=month(sysdatetime()) 
   and DATEPART(day, run_date) between 2 and 15 and Schedule='1st') --checking date between 2nd and 15th and schedule is 1st
   then DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date)+1, 0) --selecting 1st of next month

   when (DATEPART(month,run_date)=month(sysdatetime()) or run_date=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date)+1,0)) 
   and (((DATEPART(day, run_date) between 16 and 31) or (run_date=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date)+1,0))) 
   and Schedule='1st') 
   then case when (run_date=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date),0)) 
             then
             DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date),0) -- if 1st of next month, select first day of same month
             else
             DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date)+1,0) --selecting 1st of next month
             end
   when (DATEPART(month,run_date)=month(sysdatetime()) or run_date=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date),0)) 
   and (((DATEPART(day, run_date) between 16 and 31) or (run_date=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date),0))) 
   and Schedule='15th') 
   then case when (run_date=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date),0)) 
             then
             DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date),0)+14 -- if 1st of next month, select 15 of same month
             else
              DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,run_date)+1,0)+14 --selecting 15th of next month
             end
    end as NEXT_BILL_RUN_DATE
FROM mytable ;
```

Comment: I have used getdate() in the place of sysdatetime(). Still it is not working currently and populating null value in NEXT_BILL_RUN_DATE. Just to be clear the run_date variable is a 'date' datatype. Does this creating this problem?

Comment: Run_date should be the date column. Is next_bill_run_date showing null for all the dates or any specific dates? Can you provide the date for which it is showing null?

Comment: For every date value it is showing null. However I have found the solution and will post the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`case 
when schedule='1st' 
then DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, 1, RUN_DATE)), DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, 1, RUN_DATE)), 01)
when schedule='15th' and DATEPART(day, RUN_DATE)>=15
then DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, 1, RUN_DATE)), DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, 1,RUN_DATE)), 15)
when schedule='15th' and DATEPART(day, RUN_DATE)<15
then DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, RUN_DATE), DATEPART(month, RUN_DATE)), 15)
end AS NEXT_BILL_RUN_DATE`